# How insert an event on Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I currently have a feature in my app that inserts an event into Google Calendar. However, the code for this feature is over 4 years old and today, when I tested this app, I saw that the event is not being inserted into Google Calendar. However, it is on the normal Android calendar, but when I access my Google account, the event you created is not listed.

The code that performs such insertion is this:

```
public class CalendarEventCreator 
{
    private String userAccount,timeZone,accountName,displayName;
    private long calendarID;
    private boolean haveMainCalendar;
    /*
     * Columns of the Calendar's table
     * */
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = new String[]
    {
        Calendars._ID,                           // 0
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  // 1
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,         // 2
        Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,                 // 3
        Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE             // 4
    };


    private void initializer()
    {
        haveMainCalendar = false;
        userAccount = null;
        accountName = null;
        displayName = null;
        timeZone = null;
        calendarID =-1;
    }
    /*
     * Search for the first gmail account
     * TODO:support multiple google accounts on the same device
     * */
    private void getUserMainCalendar(Context ctx)
    {
        ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
        initializer();

        Cursor cur = null;
        cur = cr.query(Calendars.CONTENT_URI, COLUMNS,null,null,null);
        while(cur.moveToNext())
        {
            if (cur.getString(3).contains("@gmail.com"))
            {
                haveMainCalendar = true;
                calendarID = cur.getLong(0);
                accountName = cur.getString(1);
                displayName = cur.getString(2);
                userAccount = cur.getString(3);
                timeZone = cur.getString(4);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    public void addEventCalendar(Reminder reminder, Context ctx) throws CalendarNotFoundException, 
                                                                        ParseException
    {
        long startMilliseconds,endmilliseconds;
        Calendar calEnd;
        startMilliseconds = endmilliseconds = 0;

        getUserMainCalendar(ctx);

        if(haveMainCalendar)
        {
            ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
            calEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = DateFormat.dateFormater(reminder.getDate()+" "+reminder.getHour());
            calEnd.setTime(date);

            startMilliseconds = calEnd.getTimeInMillis()-100000;
            endmilliseconds = calEnd.getTimeInMillis();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(Events.DTSTART,startMilliseconds);
            values.put(Events.DTEND,endmilliseconds);
            values.put(Events.TITLE,reminder.getText());
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION,reminder.getCategory().getName()+" - PositivoApp");
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID,calendarID);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());


            cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
        else
            throw new CalendarNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

The SKD version is:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

set your OAuth scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.
ensure the authenticated user has write access to the calendar with the calendarId you provided (for example by calling calendarList.get() for the calendarId and checking the accessRole).

Answer (score 0):

There is a java sample on [Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) which shows how to add events:

```
  // Refer to the Java quickstart on how to setup the environment:
    // https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java
    // Change the scope to CalendarScopes.CALENDAR and delete any stored
    // credentials.

    Event event = new Event()
        .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
        .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
        .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
        .setDateTime(startDateTime)
        .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    event.setStart(start);

    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
        .setDateTime(endDateTime)
        .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    event.setEnd(end);

    String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
    event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

    EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
        new EventAttendee().setEmail("lpage@example.com"),
        new EventAttendee().setEmail("sbrin@example.com"),
    };
    event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

    EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
        new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
        new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
    };
    Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
        .setUseDefault(false)
        .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
    event.setReminders(reminders);

    String calendarId = "primary";
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
```

Don't forget to set your scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` as have been mentioned. If you're changing scopes, delete the previously saved .json credentials for the new scope to take effect.